# Выключенная кнопка в заголовке Expander'a

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть Expander у которого в заголовке прописано:

```
<Expander ...>
    <Expander.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBlock Text="Комментарии"/>
            <Button ...>
                <DockPanel>
                    <Image .../>
                </DockPanel>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander.Header>
<Expander>
```

Выглядит примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Проблема**: При нажатии на задизейбленую кнопку "+" раскрывается Expander.

Нужно чтобы область раскрывалась при клике везде, кроме кнопки.

Я понимаю что выключенная кнопка не подаёт никаких признаков жизни, но может есть хак, который позволит обойти это.

Comment: Поместите кнопку в кнопку, тогда если внутренняя кнопка задизейблена, нажатие будет обрабатываться внешней, а не проваливаться дальше в экспандер. Внешнюю кнопку можно сделать с шаблоном, имеющим только ContentPresenter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, если не хотите писать код, можно поместить кнопку в какой-то контейнер, который будет перехватывать клики, которые пропускает сквозь себя отключенная кнопка.

Это может быть, например, другая кнопка:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="StealthButton" TargetType="Button">
            <ContentPresenter/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <CheckBox Name="Enabled" Content="IsEnabled"/>
    <Expander>
        <Expander.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Comment"/>
                <Button Template="{StaticResource StealthButton}">
                    <Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Enabled}" Content="+"/>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Content"/>
    </Expander>
</StackPanel>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!